# Displacement measurement in quantum optics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics

I was following a talk where it was stated that performing a displacement $D(\alpha)$ on an optical mode, followed by a single-photon detection without number resolution, corresponds in the case of no-click to the projector $\vert\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha\vert$. The optical mode was considered to be in state $\vert 0\rangle$ or $\vert 1\rangle$.

What does this exactly mean? Also, both states $\vert 0\rangle$ and $D(\alpha)\vert 0\rangle$ have non-zero probability of getting no-click result, so where's the difference? What does that projector means?